# Get text in textview by coordinates

Tags: android, textview

How can I get text( word ) in TextView by knowing x, y coordinates of my click on screen? 
Thanks.

Comment: What does your research says? Have you googled it? This has already been asked by users, for example [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8616064/touch-coordinates-in-textview)

Comment: I cant find anythink, thats way I'm asking

Answer (score 0):

check the following code.. its working fine with me,

```
   public class ProjjActivity extends Activity {

    TextView txtview;
    float X,Y;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        txtview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tt);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        X = event.getX();
        Y = event.getY();

        txtview.setText("X: "+X+", Y: "+Y);
        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }
}
```

hope this helps you..!

Comment: Cool, but OP (Owner of the Post) is asking about, touching the `TextView` and get Text from `TextView`.

Comment: @AdilSoomro It seems bit confusing to me but if he is asking like that then its so simple. Just need to put "txtview.getText()" in click event of that textview, it will return string.

Comment: Yea that is simple, but OP wants the text of nearby area, where he touches, not the full text.