# Click on char on EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-textwatcher

I have editText view with same text. On  my way user can touch on char in editText. How I can detect on what char user create touch event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Override the touch method

```
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         Layout layout = ((TextView) v).getLayout();
            int x = (int)event.getX();
            int y = (int)event.getY();
            if (layout!=null){
                int line = layout.getLineForVertical(y);
                int characterOffset = layout.getOffsetForHorizontal(line, x);
                Log.i("index", ""+characterOffset);
                }
            return true;


    }
```

sources [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8616064/touch-coordinates-in-textview)